# How do I used data from form to make tables with js?

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table

The goal of this program is for me to put in some invoicing, press a button and add a new row with the values I have put in. I am using an external JS file to add the new rows. The code is to follow.

```js
 function myFunction() {

   var Product1 = oForm.elements["Product"].value;
   var Description1 = oForm.elements["Description"].value;
   var UnitCost1 = oForm.elements["UnitCost"].value;
   var Units1 = oForm.elements["Units"].value;
   var Total1 = UnitCost1 * Units1;
   var table = document.getElementById("invoiceTable");
   var row = table.insertRow(1);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
   var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
   cell1.innerHTML = Product1;
   cell2.innerHTML = Description1;
   cell3.innerHTML = UnitCost1;
   cell4.innerHTML = Units1;
   cell5.innerHTML = Total1;
 }
```

```css
#headder {
  height: 100px;
  width: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#Table {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
#footer {
  height: float;
  width: 1000px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%
}
th,
td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<script src="invoice.js"></script>

<head>
</head>


<body>
  <div align="center">

    <div id="headder">
      <p>Invoice Generator</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Table">

      <table id="invoiceTable">

        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Unit Cost</th>
          <th>Units</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>


      </table>

    </div>


    <div id="footer">

      <form>
        Product:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Product">
        <br>Description:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Description">
        <br>Unit Cost:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="UnitCost">
        <br>Units:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Units">
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="invoice()">
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using JQuery?

Comment: I am not very familiar with it.. but if its easier.. im always down to take it. Though i would still like to learn how to do this with JS.

Comment: Hope my answer helps :-)

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. First pull JQuery in since you said you were ok with using that.

```
<form>
        Product:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Product">
        <br>Description:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Description">
        <br>Unit Cost:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="UnitCost">
        <br>Units:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Units">
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="invoice()">
      </form><form>
        Product:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Product" id="Product">
        <br>Description:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Description" id="Description">
        <br>Unit Cost:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="UnitCost" id="UnitCost">
        <br>Units:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="Units" id="Units">
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="invoice()">
  </form>
```

-----JS-----

```
var products = $('#Product').val();
var description = $('#Description').val();
var unitCost = $('#UnitCost').val();
var units = $('Units").val();

$('#invoiceTable tr:last').after('<tr>' + 
    '<td>' + products + '</td>'  +
    '<td>' + description + '</td>'
    '<td>' + unitCost + '</td>'
    '<td>' + units + '</td>'
    '</tr>');
```

I think that should work. Notice that I added `id="field` to your `input` tags